# Best ZedGraph branch?

Tags: .net, winforms, charts, zedgraph, linechart

Correct me if I'm wrong, I've read about ZedGraph in the past, from what I recall the original author dropped it, and now there are a few branches out there.

I plan to use the library to paint multiple line charts, multiple times per second, so I'm looking for the branch that offers the best performance in this situation.

I know at least one branch has some paint optimizations, but I'm sure I'm missing a lot of things since I've never followed this project. So, could anyone point me to the different versions of ZedGraph together with the main differences between them and tell me which one to choose?

Comment: I think what you mean with the term "branch" is what is usually refereed to as a ["fork"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28software_development%29).

Comment: This fork is interesting for specific purpose : https://github.com/saleyn/ZedGraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris Champion, one of ZedGraph's project admins, posted this at the project's main page at SourceForge:

> **Project Doldrums**
>
> Unfortunately, the original creator of this project is no longer able to maintain it.
>
> As such, I am hoping that people will come along with an interest and the time to pick up the project and keep it alive. ZedGraph is well-written and documented, and it would be a shame to let it fall apart.
>
> I have complete admin rights over the project, but not the time or C# experience right now to commit to it.
>
> The domain, zedgraph.org, has been renewed for another two years, so this site isn't going anywhere.
>
> Chris Champion
>
> 2009-02-16 19:16:55 UTC by kooseefoo

This post was in Feb 2009, and of course the original domain, zedgraph.org, [now appears to be taken over by domain squatters](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/forums/forum/392231/topic/4393111).

The last updates to the project were in December of 2008. After much searching, the only fork I could find was a "ZeeGraph" one, linked below.

If you are looking for a currently maintained graphing library, you may want to look at [other projects entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3331574/161052), as there doesn't appear to be much development activity based on the original ZedGraph project.

- [Zedgraph official project page at SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/)
- ["Zeegraph" Fork](https://github.com/discomurray/zeegraph)
- [SO: Can the ZedGraph charting library for .NET be recommended?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/536018/161052)
- [A 2007 Redmond Developer article about ZedGraph](http://reddevnews.com/articles/2007/06/01/open-source-for-windows.aspx)

Comment: As can be seen in the "Can the ZedGraph charting library for .NET be recommended?", there is at least another branch used in TickZoom, and which seems to be more actively maintained. Also, when I looked into this library some months ago, I believe I saw another one which seemed active... but I cannot find it now, maybe it was some other library, or my eyes just fooled me when I looked at the files age. Since this is gonna be for just line charts, I could draw them myself, but I'm trying to avoid it, and the other charting libraries I've seen didn't convince me enough.